# ¿ Porqué Angular arroja este error NG6002?

Tags: angular10

Angular arroja este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aca muestro `product.service.ts`

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
// firebase
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList} from '@angular/fire/database';

import { Product } from '../models/product';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

  productList: AngularFireList<any>;
  // para almacenar temporalmente el producto seleccionado
  selectedProduct: Product = new Product();
  constructor(private firebase: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  getProduct()
  {
    return this.productList = this.firebase.list('products');
  }

  insertProduct(product: Product)
  {
    this.productList.push({
      name: product.name,
      category: product.category,
      location: product.location,
      price: product.price
    });
  }

  updateProduct(product: Product)
  {
    this.productList.update(product.$key, {
      name: product.name,
      category: product.category,
      location: product.location,
      price: product.price
    });
  }

  deleteProduct($key: string)
  {
    this.productList.remove($key);
  }

}
```

Aca `admin.module.ts`

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AdminRoutingModule } from './admin-routing.module';
import { NavComponent } from './components/nav/nav.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './components/products/product/product.component';
import { ProductsComponent } from './components/products/products.component';
import { ProductListComponent } from './components/products/product-list/product-list.component';
import { ProductService } from '../core/services/product.service';
// material design
import { MaterialModule } from './../material/material.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [ProductComponent, NavComponent, ProductsComponent, ProductListComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ProductService,
    AdminRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule,
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario importar el servicio en el modulo. Lo puede llamar directamente desde tu componente y angular a través de el sistema de inyección de dependencia se encargara de hacer la gestión.

> ## [Providing services](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services#providing-services)
>
> Debes registrar por lo menos un proveedor de cualquier servicio que
> vayas a usar. El proveedor puede ser
> parte de los propios metadatos del servicio, haciendo que ese servicio
> esté disponible en todas partes, o puede registrar proveedores con
> módulos o componentes especificos.
>
> Por defecto, el comando CLI `ng g s` de angular registra un provedor
> con el inyector `root` en tu servicio agregando la metadata in el
> decorador `@Injectable()`
>
> `content_copy @Injectable({  providedIn: 'root', })` Cuando tu
> provees el servicio en la raiz, Angular crea una unica, compartida
> instancia de HeroService y lo inyecta en cualquier clase que pregunte
> por el. Registrarlo de esta manera tambien permite a Angular optimizar
> la aplicacion removiendo el servicio de la la aplicacion compilada si
> este no se uso.

Solo quita  `ProductService` de los imports, y llama directamente a tu servicio desde su path.

Solo en el caso de que tengas dos servicios con el mismo nombre pero que actúen diferente en condiciones preestablecidas (movil y web, por ejemplo) usas los `providers` para que angular haga la sustitución de uno u otro dependiendo la necesidad.

Comment: muchas gracias solucionado!